# How to change the tab name of a custom object?

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, tab

I have a managed package custom object whose name\label I would like to change. However, it is apparently not possible to use the Override feature to change custom object labels. Is there a way in which I could change that custom object's tab name ? I'm guessing it's possible in some way through Visualforce, but I've only used Visualforce to customize the behavior of the tab (sending it to a VF page), not the actual tab name.

...or if you know a way to change the label of a managed package's custom object that would be even better.....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Go to "Rename Tabs and Labels" from setup and rename the tab.

Comment: omg - I don't feel foolish at all. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, only the package developer can edit the Label of a Managed Custom Object.

From **[Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_custom_objects)** :

> #### Editable Properties After Package Promotion or Installation
>
> [Only Package Developer Can Edit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#only_definition)
>
> - Description
> - Label
> - Plural Label
> - Record Name
> - Record Name Display Format
> - Starts with a Vowel Sound